# The morphism induced in the derived category and in the homotopy category

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, derived-categories, morphism

During a lecture my professor made an observation, she said that it can happen the following fact but she never explained how/why: let $\mathcal{A}$ a category; there are examples of morphisms $f\colon A^\bullet\to B^\bullet$ of complexes such that the morphism induced by $f$ in the derived category $D(\mathcal{A})$ is zero but the morphism induced by $f$ in the homotopy category $K(\mathcal{A})$ is not zero.

I'd like to understand how this can happen. Can anyone give me any examples please?

---

I'd like to precise that I know things like cone, cylinders, exact triangles.

Comment: There can be objects which are zero in the derived category but not in the homotopy category. The identity map on such an object would be an example.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri I think that what you are saying cannot be possible since the objects of the three categories $\mathcal{A}, D(\mathcal{A}), K(\mathcal{A})$ are - by definition - the same ones. Right?

Comment: Well, there can be objects which are isomorphic to zero in the derived category but not in the homotopy category: chain complexes which have zero homology but which are not contractible. Some examples are discussed at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103056/when-is-an-acylic-chain-complex-contractible.